# Strange output of _thread module in Windows

Tags: python, multithreading

When I was learning Threads I tried the following example code:

```
import _thread
def child(tid):
    print('Hello from thread',tid)
def parent():
    i=0
    while True:
        i+=1
        _thread.start_new_thread(child,(i,))
        if input()=='q':break
parent()
```

The result I expected was like

```
Hello from thread 1

Hello from thread 2

Hello from thread 3
q
```

I got above result with similar code on CentOS 7. However on Win8, the result is very strange:

```
Hello from thread
Hello from thread

Hello from thread 1

Hello from thread 2
q
Hello from thread 3
4
5
```

Can anyone explain to me why the same code generates different results(and the one on win8 seems to be wrong)?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one stdout buffer in a process, and `print` is not thread safe.  You can get garbled output like this on any OS.  It's a combination of timing and buffering, and console output on CentOS and Windows is different.  You need to synchronise buffered output, for example using a Lock around the `print`.

It is a feature of threading that you do not know what order your threads will be executed in, unless you synchronise in some way.  Although it appears that CentOS is "right" and Windows is "wrong", you were just lucky to get that sequence on CentOS (or unlucky, depending on your point if view)

Comment: I understand that multiple threads working simultaneously may cause problems. But this code runs them one by one and each exits almost instantaneously. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you say t executes "one-by-one"?  You do not wait for each to finish before starting the next.

Comment: Because I start only one thread in each While loop, and I can proceed to the next loop only if the script receives any input other than 'q'.

Comment: So, do you wait for each to finish before hitting <Return>?  Bear in mind that `input()` is also using the same IO system as the worker threads.